# Swagger does not list C# default interface implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

To use composition-over-inheritance on my C# ASP.NET Core controllers, I added several interfaces to my controllers. These interfaces contain 'default interface implementations' (new in C# 8.0), so I can add those interfaces to several of my controllers to allow re-use of those endpoints. However, Swagger will not list those methods.

Example code:

```
public class MyController : IMyReusableReadInterface<MyViewModel>
{
    public async Task<ActionResult<MyViewModel>> MyDomainAction(...)
    {
        // Implementation goes here
    }
}
```

```
public interface IMyReusableReadInterface<IViewModel>
{
    public async Task<ActionResult<IViewModel>> Get<IViewModel>(...)
    {
        // Implementation goes here
    }
}
```

In this example, the action `MyDomainAction` is listed on Swagger, but the `Get` method from the interface is not listed. How are methods on an ASP.NET Core controller detected? Any idea why default interface implementations are not detected? Or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:
@DavidG asked why not use inheritance: Because I want to compose my controller, without being forced to use all inherited base controllers. For example, I can now add `IWriteControllerBase` without adding `IReadControllerBase` (yes, contrived example, bear with me). If I would use inheritance, `WriteControllerBase` would extend `ReadControllerBase`, and would also get those unwanted methods.

Comment: Why would you use an interface here? That's not what they were intended for. Just create an abstract base `class` instead.

Comment: I would like to prevent a deep inheritance structure, but use composition instead. I'll add some explanation to the post.

Comment: I don't know why you would want to do this with a controller anyway. They should be pretty thin slices of code.

Comment: What library/framework do you use - Swashbuckle, Swagger-Net, something else?

Comment: To identify something as controller, there are some basic criteria one of them if you inherit from controllerbase or use apicontroller attribute, is your interface follows the basic rules to be called as controller.

Comment: The way default interface methods work, the method is only accessible through `IMyReusableReadInterface<IViewModel>`, not `MyController`. The feature is intended to function as a "traits" mechanism, not a way to add "inherited" methods, so it would be difficult for a framework to use them in a consistent way starting only from a concrete type. It's legal for interfaces to define "conflicting" methods, for example, because they don't actually "conflict" if you're going through the interface, but a framework would be forced to choose.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: I understand your point, if there would be two interfaces defining the same method, which one would the framework have to execute?
I'll just have to find another way.